# Too many media items in single node creating performance issue

Tags: performance-optimization

We are facing lot of issues related to Media library dialog box such as below-

- Media dialog box takes too much time to load
- Saving Item takes time after updating image in experience editor
- Tree node doesn't open and Times out

We observed that there are lot of media items within single node almost around 3000 media items
Can you suggest best practices which will help to improve performance? Can we apply bucketing on the media node? will it help?

Comment: max 100 children is the best best practices. indeed create folders or a bucket

Answer (score 7):

As a best practice, there should not more than 100 items under any node in Sitecore, Since Media in Sitecore are also store as Items so it is applicable for Media library as well. If you have more than 3000 media items under a single node then definitely it should restructure.

Now come to the point of bucketing, creating bucket is an option in your case but I personally don't think it a good option because you will need to update the system template for this and changing a system template is not a good practice.

But yes, you can structure the items based on the item name creating media folder structure with item name's initial 3-4 characters. such as if your media item name is "*John-profile*" folder structure will be like J > O > H, similar to the bucketing but folder type will be Medial folder. You can use PowerShell script for this of can write your custom C# code.

For newly created items you can write your event handler for `item:created` event. There is an old question on Sitecore 6.6 but this discussion is applicable for current Sitecore version as well - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19838143/avoiding-100-item-limit-in-the-media-library

Comment: Thanks Mahendra for your response. We will try to apply this however is there any performance tuning recommendations for Media library dialog box. It is really slow to open and frustrating thing is its get timeout after spending so much time for selecting any media Item.

Comment: As per my knowledge, there is no performance tuning specific to the Media library dialog box. but can you please try by switching the SPEAK UI to old sheer one if it improves the time.